# Angular 2 + PHP: CORS preflight issues

Tags: php, apache, angular, cors, wamp

I am new to using Angular 2 (and front end development in general), and I've hit a problem with CORS.
Essentially, I have two HTTP servers running - one is my localhost on port 4200 (the Angular 2 CLI server which runs the application) and the other is a WAMP server on port 8080 which holds the PHP scripts I use to communicate to a remote SQL server.

My problem is that I keep getting CORS related errors when running my application.  The latest error I am receiving is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/hvTool2_Ang2/src/app/php/pullData.php. Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have tried the following methods, as per other Stack Overflow questions and answers:

A. Added the following code to my http.conf for Apache (WAMP server) and then restarted the services.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

B. I have added the following PHP code before my echo statement in PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

C. I know some people have suggested turning off Web Security Services in Chrome.  I can do this, but I would rather see CORS implemented correctly.

I don't quite grasp what this preflight thing is.  From what I have gathered, the CORS preflight is only sent on certain occassions (non-GET or non-POST HTTP requests or/and HTTP requests that have options defined [please correct me if I am wrong]).  Also, I figure I am meant to reply to this CORS preflight with something - but I am unsure what.

This is my Angular 2 code:

```
getData(routing: string, functionindex: number, dataarray) {
    var sentData = JSON.stringify(dataarray);
    var sentArray = [routing, functionindex, sentData];
    var returnedJSON;
    var url;
    if (this.dev_env == true){
      url = this.devPHPfolderURL;
    }
    else{
      url = this.prodPHPfolderURL;
    }
    let headers = new Headers();
    //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //CORS issue
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); //no CORS issue

    return this.http.post(url, sentArray)
        .subscribe(
            result => returnedJSON = result,
            () => console.log("Failed..."),
            () => console.log("Completed: " + returnedJSON)
        );
  }
```

This is the PHP function which executes the commands and echos the response:
function queryDB($query){

```
$myServer = "SERVER"; //Actual variable answers were changed for this post.
$myUser = "USER";
$myPass = "PASS";
$myDB = "DATABASE"; 

// connection to the database
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$result = odbc_prepare($connection, $query);
odbc_execute($result)or die(odbc_error($connection));
odbc_close($connection);
odbc_fetch_array($result);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

while ($info = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
   $total[] = $info;
}

echo json_encode(odbc_fetch_array($total); //To send to JavaScript
```

}

**EDIT:** 
Weirdly enough, when I use:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

No CORS issue occurs.
But when I use:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

A CORS issue occurs.  I need to return a JSON object to JavaScript.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Weirdly enough" — It isn't weird. CORS only has to explicitly allow a Content-Type header when you set the value to something that isn't allowed in the `enctype` of a `<form>`

Comment: I apologise - I understand now that CORS preflight occurs when you don't use particular headers (so it doesn't occur when text/plain is used).  How do I use 'application/json' as a content type then?

Comment: — By having your server respond correctly to the preflight options request.

Comment: I've got PHP accepting the preflight request by just moving the headers code I already had to the root of the script, rather than just within the function.  My problem now is that there appears to be no difference in what is returned to JavaScript between when I used 'text/plain' and 'application/json'.  The initial reason I wanted the content-type 'application/json' header was to get a JSON response from PHP.  Now I am getting a 'Response' object where the PHP response is in the response body.  I figure this is a different question to ask though.  Thanks for your assistance Quentin.

Comment: The Content-Type request header tells the server what format the data you are sending is in. If you want to ask the server for a specific data format you need an Accept header (and the server has to be set up to do content-negotiation based on it).

Comment: I've updated the PHP code to look at the content-type request header and then echo the data back depending upon what was requested.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

In the service of Angular use a different header:

```
this.reqOpts = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }};
```

this gonna works, but I can't understand why it is necessary in the client-side